# Enforcing upper case for const under Visual Studio with editoconfig

Tags: visual-studio, editorconfig

I'm writing an editorconfig file to enforce some coding styles and I'd like to enforce that constants should be uppercase, so I created the following rules in the editorConfig file:

```
dotnet_naming_rule.constants_must_be_uppercase.symbols                 = public_constants
dotnet_naming_symbols.public_constants.applicable_kinds                = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.public_constants.applicable_accessibilities      = *
dotnet_naming_symbols.public_constants.required_modifiers              = const

dotnet_naming_rule.constants_must_be_uppercase.style                   = uppercase_with_underscore_separator
dotnet_naming_style.uppercase_with_underscore_separator.capitalization = all_upper
dotnet_naming_style.uppercase_with_underscore_separator.word_separator = _

dotnet_naming_rule.constants_must_be_uppercase.severity                = warning
```

I'm testing this with the following code:

```
namespace XYZ
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public const string Bar = "bar";
    }
}
```

However, Visual Studio does not indicate that the line is not correct. Is it a bug or is my file incorrect?

Answer (score 9):

Leaving this here for if other people stumble upon this question like I did.

These are the .editorconfig lines that I figured work for enforcing upper case constants:

```
# Constants are UPPERCASE
dotnet_naming_rule.constants_should_be_upper_case.severity = suggestion
dotnet_naming_rule.constants_should_be_upper_case.symbols = constants
dotnet_naming_rule.constants_should_be_upper_case.style = constant_style

dotnet_naming_symbols.constants.applicable_kinds = field, local
dotnet_naming_symbols.constants.required_modifiers = const

dotnet_naming_style.constant_style.capitalization = all_upper
```

Comment: This works for fields, but doesn't for locals in VS code :/